# Binding method when a custom header is provided

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

So I am trying to implement a WS on WebAPI that checks received header for an optional custom parameter, and processes it and its body.

I am playing with Postman in order to test it. When I call method without custom parameter on header, everything goes right. When I include my custom parameter on the header, my method does not fire.

```
[HttpPost]
        [ResponseType(typeof(ResultModel))]
        public HttpResponseMessage Add([FromBody] InputModel oModel)
        {
            ResultModel oResult;

// Process oModel

// Check if my "X-Custom-Parameter exists
if(Request.Headers.GetValues("X-Custom-Parameter").FirstOrDefault() != null){
 // Do something with custom parameter and oModel
}

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, oResult);
        }
```

When calling from Postman I get following message:

```
Error: Header name must be a valid HTTP Token ["X‐Custom-Parameter"]
```

And Header:

```
POST /myapi/path
X‐Custom-Parameter: 123Kartofen
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 6d1da8b9-9871-439e-8e5d-79c22978b4cd
```

Though I am missing some configuration. I have surfing web for hours and read about Handlers and Filters, however I don't think is what I am looking for.

Comment: When do you get this error? From Postman itself or you get a 500 from WebApi with this message?

Comment: Well... this is weird... After a reboot it started working :/ I am trying VS2019, It was a possible bug? Thank you anyway for all your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Rename your custom header to **Custom-Parameter** instead of **X‐Custom-Parameter** .Because "X-" Prefix  in Application Protocols are Deprecated

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648

Answer (score 0):

Check your postman, are you sending the header with hyphen or underscore. X_ or X- ?

Comment: It's a typo. I was sending "X-" but tried both possibilities looking for a solution.